# Is there a way to invoke a function when error occurs in lightning-record-edit-form in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I would like to know if I can set a handler function so that it will be invoked when errors occur while submitting a record-edit-form in LWC. By errors I mean, required field errors. 'onerror' event is not working.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation there is a custom  event named error that is emited upon failure.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/example

For including the error message just add lightning-messages immediately before or after the lightning-edit-form

You can also override and manually capture it .

In your submit button add an attribute `onerror` and call a method `handleError`

```
<lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Create Account" onerror={handleError}> </lightning-button>
```

have not tested it , try using the below

```
handleError(event) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail))
 }
```

Comment: Hi Mohith, I am not getting any call back to handleError() function.